# Problems understanding associations in Sequelize for eager loading

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im trying to understand, how sequelize is doing eager loading and why it is not working for me.

Please assume, I create following tables via sequelize migrate command:

**Users table:**

```
return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      .... other columns
}
```

**Items table:**

```
return queryInterface.createTable('Items', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        }, 
        insertUserId: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
                model: 'Users',
                key: 'id',
                as: 'insertUserId'
            }
        },
        ..... some other columns 
}
```

**Items model (this association works perfectly):**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
  .... configuration of columns
  });

  Item.associate = (models) => {
   Item.belongsTo(models.User, {
    as: 'insertUser'
   });
  };

  Item.associate = (models) => {
    Item.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'editUser'
  });

  return Item;
};
```

**Users model (that's the tricky part for me):**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    .... configuration of columns
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
        - TRICKY ASSOCIATION - 
  };

  return User;
};
```

**My goal:**

I want to get all items with included users in the itemController (that works) but I also want to get all users and include all associated items in the userController (LEFT JOIN, right?). Eager loading is able to do that (am I right?)

**wanted output:**

```
{ 
 id: '0',
 name: 'username', 
 insertedItems: [
  { <item_1> },
  { <item_n> }
 ]
}
```

**userController**

```
function getUsersItems(year) {
    return User.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Item,
            as: 'insertedItems'
        }],
        attributes: ['id', 'name']
    });
}
```

**I tried the following in the user model:**

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Item, {
        as: 'insertedItems',
        foreignKey: 'id'
    });
};
```

As I understood the docs correctly, 'hasMany' is the right thing to use here. An alias is also important ('insertedItems'). Is there anything, I was missing out?

Im using sequelize 4.15.0 and nodejs 9.2.0.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Because I have Items associated to multiple users (insertUser, editUser) i need to specify the correct foreignkey

```
User.hasMany(models.Item, {
    as: 'items',
    foreignKey: 'insertUserId'
});
```